# mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away - max_allowed_packet no good

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have seen about 20 pages pertaining to this error on StackExchange's sites (and others) and they all point towards doing:

**C:\wamp64\bin\mariadb\mariadb10.4.10\my.ini**: `max_allowed_packet = 128M` (or higher)`

**C:\wamp64\bin\mariadb\mariadb10.4.10\my.ini**: `wait_timeout = 28800` (or higher)

which we have tried, but it's still reporting the "mysql has gone away" error.

We have also tried those config settings under the `[wampmariadb64]` and `[mysqld]` sections, to which we discovered that the `[wampmariadb64]` takes presidence when using WAMP, and those settings were applied, but no we're still getting the error intermittently..

There was also a suggestion to try to set ssl settings:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = false;
```

But that didn't work.

They also suggest that we might have a loop problem in our php, which it originally was, but then we fixed it, and we're still getting the error.

**Hints:**

**a)** We've only been getting the error since the PHP loop problem which we've fixed.

**b)** Our log files in WAMP's "C:\wamp64\bin\mariadb\mariadb10.4.10\data" are maxed out to 64Mb, which is what we set it to, but it maxes out on the initial use (on startup and first loading a statement). Is this normal? The log files are named: "ib_logfile0" and "ib_logfile1".

**c)**  About 50 (or so) singular statements after startup it gives the error. The error goes away after an hour of no statement executions, apprx (not always but just about an hour or two later).

Could I please just get some pages to read on troubleshooting the error like this page:

[http://ronaldbradford.com/: mysql server has gone away 2013-01-02](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/sqlstatehy000-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away-2013-01-02/)

Thanks.

**Update**

I was meaning that we've been editing and trying to change the settings in the `C:\wamp64\bin\mariadb\mariadb10.4.10\my.ini` file, and not the `php.ini` sorry. Have corrected above sentences to clarify.

**Update**

I discovered that a script that automates the creation of a database.sql via `mysqydump` has sometimes been creating 0kb .sql files, which is required for the other scripts to move on.

I'm looking at the following command, which I have just removed `2>&1` from and going to try that:

```
exec("mysqldump --port={$GLOBALS['SQL_Port']} --user={$GLOBALS['SQL_Username']} --password={$GLOBALS['SQL_Password']} --host={$GLOBALS['SQL_Host_NoPort']} {$Database} --result-file={$DumpDatabase}.sql"); 

// 2>&1
```

**Update**

This error is now showing up:

```
Error in processing request
Error code: 200
Error text: OK (rejected)
It seems that the connection to server has been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status.
```

**Update**

Discovered the mariadb logs but they don't say much:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.10 started; log sequence number 140336; transaction id 21
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from c:\wamp64\bin\mariadb\mariadb10.4.10\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200723 19:16:23
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2020-07-23 19:16:23 0 [Note] wampmariadb64: ready for connections.
Version: '10.4.10-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2020-07-23 19:27:43 0 [Note] wampmariadb64 (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2020-07-23 19:27:43 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2020-07-23 19:27:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2020-07-23 19:27:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-07-23 19:27:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to c:\wamp64\bin\mariadb\mariadb10.4.10\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-23 19:27:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200723 19:27:43
2020-07-23 19:27:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 140345; transaction id 22
2020-07-23 19:27:44 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-07-23 19:27:44 0 [Note] wampmariadb64: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: i think max_allowed_packet and wait_timeout you should change it not in php.ini, i think in the mysql config file

Comment: `max_allowed_packet` is a MySQL setting, not a PHP setting (whatever article that suggests otherwise is completely unreliable); you can't even change it from PHP. In any case, that's a pretty generic error that can have totally different reasons (for instance, if you attempt to connect to something that is not a MySQL server). What are you doing exactly when the error triggers?

Comment: To trigger the errors: we're just adding content into the database via PhpMyAdmin, record by record. And I'll update the post because what I meant was, the mysql setting in `C:\wamp64\bin\mariadb\mariadb10.4.10\my.ini`.

Comment: I just did a reinstall of WAMP and then added my databases (2mb), and after about an hour (or about 50 executed queries) it displayed the same error.

Comment: What's a part of the MySQL server that's on a timer for about an hour or so? Like a cookie or some memory handling setting. It seems to be precisely about an hour, then goes away after about 15mins, then comes back again.

Answer (score 0):

It had something to do with starting WAMP in Windows 10 Scheduled Task Manager, starting it as a new task. Probably because I didn't start it with Administrator privileges.

Once I removed the Scheduled Task: Start WAMP @ Logon -it seemed to work again.